# Scrolling does not work correctly in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in which I implement this method of adding a cell.

```
private func addNewMessage() {
    let tuplForAdd = dataSource.newMessage()
    if tuplForAdd.needNewSection {
        collectionView.insertSections(dataSource.indexSet)
    } else {
        collectionView.insertItems(at: [tuplForAdd.indexPath])
    }
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: tuplForAdd.indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

If you do not add anything else everything will be fine.
But if you set `contentInset`, then the scroll starts working later on the value that I wrote in `contentInset`.

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64,0,0,0)
collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64,0,0,0)
```

The controller I create with `xib` file.

----------------//-----------------------------

Edit after a partial solution to the problem.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Try contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior property.

Comment: Сan tell which object to call this function, I found only this automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving 64 use following margin,

```
var topMargin = headerHeight + 15
```

To use automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property,

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topMargin, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

And if you just want to give margin outside your collection view, then you can try this also,

If you want to give margin around your collectionview then use,

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake ( CGFloat top,CGFloat left,CGFloat bottom,CGFloat right);
```

> Swift 3

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(topMargin, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

This will solve your problem..

Comment: I thank you for the answer, the problem solved but a new one appeared, as soon as I wrote the delegate method func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets, my header was missing.

Comment: can you share the screen shot ? What you mean by header ?

Comment: I load photos with problem.

Comment: Just to clarify this problem might be with your constraints, it has nothing to do with scrolling problem. :)